# verbs usage for TION and ING

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain the rationale of adding TION to a verb.   In other words,  when I take a verb such as  LIMIT and turn it into a noun I can make it limit,  limiting, or limitation.   The word Limitation means something a little different than limit or limiting.   IS there a rule or explanation about this applies to all or at least most cases?

Comment: I can't immediately think of "limiting" being used as a *noun* - but it can be used as an *adjective*, e.g. "a limiting feature".  If you have an example of it being used as a noun, please clarify.

Comment: @TrevorD your limiting this question is showing your limited view.

Answer (score 1):

As often, the answer to questions like this goes back to German, Greek or (in this case) Latin

My now agéd Lewis and Short tells me that it all starts with the noun *limes* (genitive *limitis*).  The entry tells us its original meaning was *cross-path, balk between fields*:-

> The Romans usually had in their fields two broad and two narrower paths; the principal balk from east to west was called the *limes decumanus*; that from north to south was called *cardo*.

From there the use developed to mean any *boundary* or *limit*.  It stretched to the legal idea of a *distinction or difference*.

The related verb, *limito* had the supine (which forms the past passive tenses and participle) *limitatum*.  From verbs like *limito*, nouns can be formed into a third declension noun ending *-atio* (genitive *emphasized text*-ationis).  So *limito* means, say Lewis and Short,

> enclose with boundaries or limits, and to fix settle or determine {my summary, not quote}

So words derived from Latin first conjugation verbs, are formed in this way:  *limitation*m as in *devastation, station, consternation*.  Second, third and fourth conjugation verbs lead to nouns ending in *-itio*, as *tradition, ignition, repetition*.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are not adding anything to a verb, to get *limitation*. Rather, it is a word that is borrowed from Latin (probably from *limitatio* which has *-n* added in all declensions), where it was ... I don't know, does it matter? It looks to me like a Future Active Participle nominalized with the suffix -on; But I just heard about the Future Active yesterday, and I frequently write *heared*, wrongly, so what do I know?

French wiktionary says [limitatio](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/limitatio) was built adding the noun building suffix *-io* to *limitatus*, the past participle of *limito*. en.WT says the suffix reflects a Proto-Indo-European suffix that "Derives adjectives, nouns denoting burden, authority." that has various reconstructed forms.

Of course, the suffix [-tion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tion) can be backfashioned on existing words, but it is not grammatically productive the way *-ing* is.